# return type in C

Tags: c, return

If we do not specify a return type, compiler assumes an implicit return type as `int`. I tried to return a `char` and it worked fine in GCC. I just defined it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

char fun(char ch)
{
      return ch;
}

int main()
{
        char ch = fun('A');
        printf("ch : %c\n",ch);
}
```

But, In below program not specify a return type, but

```
#include <stdio.h>

char fun(char ch)
{

}

int main()
{
        char ch = fun('A');
        printf("ch : %c\n",ch);
}
```

and it worked fine means return a `char`. Why?

Why not return `int` return type by default?

Comment: It is not the return type that's missing. its the return *value* you left out, and invoke *undefined behavior* in doing so. What you observed is irrelevant once you invoke UB.

Comment: But without return type, why return char 'A'?

Comment: I don't think you know what the *return type* **is**. Both of your functions have `char` for their declared return type. It is the return *value* that is missing in the second example, and as I said, failing to fulfill the promise *you made* by declaring your function returns `char` and failing to actually do so, invokes undefined behavior. What you observe "it returns" after that is irrelevant. It's *undefined*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been pointing out, it seem that the goal of a return value has been misunderstood.

### Function declarations

when declaring a function you are not forced to give it a body, you are telling the compiler that somewhere in the full program there will be such function.

This :

```
char fun(char ch);
int main()
{
    char ch = fun('A');
}
```

Is still valid C, and compile ( to an object file )

By doing this you are telling the compiler that the function does not exists now but should exists later. This is quite helpful when using library or other object files to be linked to form your final program.

unfortunately C compilers are still not smart enough to infer what was exactly your intention if you write

```
int main()
{
    char ch = fun('A');
}
```

it will try to best guess by defaulting to a mostly wrong type for your `fun`, or just stop because guessing would be wrong.

One practical example to this would be

#### func.c

```
char fun(char ch)
{
    return ch;
}
```

Compile with `cc -c fun.c` will compile a `fun.o` object file

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char fun(char ch); // fun exist in fun.c but not in main.c this is a way yo tell that the function exists

int main()
{
    char ch = fun('A');
    printf("ch : %c\n",ch);
}
```

Compile with `cc -c main.c` will compile a `main.o` object file

then link the two files with `cc fun.o main.o -o main`, it will link the two object file into the program `main`.

### return statement

the `return` statement have two goal

- set the value to be send to the caller
- stop the execution flow of the current function and return to the caller execution flow

in your function prototype you will have to declare what your function would return. which seems quite some extra code when having only one return statement per function, but what would make sure you are keeping your promise ?

What if you have two return statement in your function, ... returning different type? what should be the inferred type of your function?

What if you are returning an `int` should the computer store it in the `char`? what if the char is too big? what if you return a `struct` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Actually in both cases you have specified a return type. In the second case, your function is :

```
char fun(char ch)
{

}
```

which specifies `char` as the return type. What you have not specified in your second case is the return value of the function (which will lead to undefined behavior).

***Note*** : In general, a function declaration has the following structure :

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
   body of the function
}
```

So you have clearly declared the return type of your function to be `char`. See [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm) for more information.

Comment: But inside the function not specify the return type.

Comment: @Anjan the return type is specified next to the function name, not inside it.

Comment: means compiler internally check function return type. right?